# Collect remarks for task in django-viewflow

Tags: django, django-viewflow

Is there way to collect remarks for specific task when user submits his task form?

Lets say i have below step to perform approval, where i'm exposing only `ìs_approved`field which will get stored in actual process model. Now along with `ìs_approved`, i also want to capture `remarks` for the same task.

```
approve = (
    flow.View(
        UpdateProcessView,
        fields=["is_approved"],
        task_title="Approve the document"
    ).Permission(
        lambda process: 'core.can_approve_{}'.format(process.process.type)
    ).Next(this.check_approve)
)


Task1 -> Start -> Capture remarks from requester
Task2 -> Verification -> Capture remarks from the guy who performs verification
Task3 -> Approval -> Capture remarks from the guy who approves
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. Just like in common django application. There is no viewflow specific functionality involved here.

The simplest one, would add `comments` field to the process model and set `fields=['is_approved', 'comments'] for the update view.

For more complicated cases, you can use your own views and models to store comments.

Comment: If that's the case, i need to maintain separate model to capture remarks against each task. As you can see my updated question, one process instance may have many task reamrks

Comment: in that case, you can set custom Flow.task_class, or use separate TaskRemarks model.